# API for a website: separate backend and frontend with an API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, cordova

I am developping a website and and app (developped via cordova; the app will have almost the same functionalities as the website).
The website exists and uses a lot of JS (I am also thinking of using AngularJS). 
One option seems to:
- create an API to separate my frontend and my backend on my website. In this way I could use the same API to developp my app and deploy angularJS easly.
Is that a "real" goog idea or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you got it! That's exactly how it's done.

Developers will separate the backend and the frontend, and make requests from their apps (be it a web-app, Cordova, or whatever) to their API.

AngularJS is a great option for frontend work.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer: so I should developp my website and my app using the same API ?

Comment: If they are identical, there's no reason not to. With Cordova it's also possible to develop an app and a website with the same code.